# using scp command to transfer files keeping the same names intact?

Tags: scp, file-transfer

Using `scp` command I want to move files from local system to a remote system. I'm doing something like this:

```
$ scp file1 root@abc:root /root/tmp
```

With this command I'm able to upload `file1` to `abc:/root`, but the problem is that it changes the names to `tmp` like in my case, I want to keep the name the same as the original and just copy it to the folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$ scp file1 root@abc:/root/tmp/
```

This would also work:

```
$ scp file1 root@abc:~/tmp/
```

If the directory `/root/tmp` isn't on the remote system abc, you can do this, and rsync will create the remote directory for you:

```
$ rsync -ave ssh file1 root@abc:/root/tmp
```

Lastly if you have to use `ssh` you can do this:

```
$ cat file1 | ssh root@abc "mkdir /root/tmp; cat >> /root/tmp/file1"
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the `/root` directory on `abc` does not contain a `tmp` sub-directory. One more thing: you're using an extra `root` in your command line. (It should be `scp file1 root@abc:/root/tmp`)

Here's what you should do:

- First create the required sub-directory on `abc`:

  ```
  ssh root@abc 'mkdir /root/tmp'
  ```
- Then copy the file into the newly-created sub-directory:

  ```
  scp file1 root@abc:/root/tmp
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the final parameter, and the copied file will be `/root/file1`

```
scp file1 root@abc:root
```

Comment: but i want to place the FILE in root/tmp folder

Answer (score 0):

When a destination is not followed by a slash, it is interpreted as a new name for the file unless that folder already exists. So either:

```
$ scp file1 root@abc:root /root/tmp/
```

Or create the `/root/tmp/` directory, then:

```
$ scp file1 root@abc:root /root/tmp
```